# Calculate image ratio and apply value to query string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that grabs the dimensions of the resulting image from a cropper tool, and based on the result of dividing height/width, generates a value which is used as the image aspect ratio. I then have this value inserted into the query string `url: urlLocation + imageid.value + "/orientation/" + orientation + "/image/" + saveImage,`. The issue is that the logic to find the image ratio is not operating correctly, and is seeing all images cropped(whether they are square(height = width), portrait or landscape) as "SQUARE".

```
$submitButton = $('<div class="btn btn-success submit"></div>')
            .text('Submit ' + imageid.value).appendTo($(".submit-well"))
            .on('click', function () {

              //var USERNAME = "bob";
              //var PASSWORD = "bobpass";
              var urlLocation = "http://www.url.com/rest/v1/cms/story/";
              var saveImage = encodeURIComponent(dataUrl);

              //USED IF ORIENTATION HAS TO BE MANUALLY SELECTED
              //var orientation = $("#orientation").val();
              //

              var resultHeight = $("#result").height();
              var resultWidth = $("#result").width();
              var divide = resultHeight / resultWidth;
              var precision = divide.toFixed(1);

              if (precision == 1.77) {
                        orientation = "PORTRAIT";
              } 
              if(precision == 0.56) {
                        orientation = "LANDSCAPE";
              } 
              if(resultHeight === resultWidth){
                        orientation = "SQUARE";
                        console.log(orientation);
              }

              $.ajax({
                  method: "PUT",
                  dataType: 'jsonp',
                  /*headers: {
                      "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD)
                    },*/
                  url: urlLocation + imageid.value + "/orientation/" + orientation + "/image/" + saveImage,
                  /*data: {
                    imageid: imageid.value,
                    orientation: orientation,
                    image: saveImage,
                  },*/
                  success: function (data) {
                    $(".share-link").html("<div class='alert alert-success'><p>Success! " + imageid.value +" was posted.</p></div>");
                      console.log(data);
                  },
                  error: function (data) {
                    $(".share-link").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'><p>Couldn't send photo: <b>"+ imageid.value + "</b></p></div>");
                  }
              });
            });
```

Comment: What are the results you're getting for `resultHeight` and `resultWidth`?

Comment: @krillgar - resultHeight and resultWidth give me the value in pixels of the image in the result div.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that is what they're doing, but without any images to test with, figuring out why `resultHeight === resultWidth` is impossible. Looking at the code in your question, that's the only way that `orientation` will be assigned to `"SQUARE"`.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why using the division? resultHeight > resultWidth => PORTRAIT and resultWidth > resultHeight => LANDSCAPE should have the same effect without leaving the possibillity of an empty value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code contains a lot of references to your project so I can't really test it.
However, if I was to find a likely cause, I'd say it's in the lines where you are testing `precision` for equality.

As you may recall, the *golden rule* is to never, ever compare two floats for equality. Because of the way floats are stored in memory (in exponential notation), that can lead to unexpected results.
For example, this code will return `false`:

```
console.log(0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3)
```

The problem is that you're first using `.toFixed()` to (correctly) converting the float to a string. However, you then compare the resulting string with a float, which means that JavaScript will re-convert the string to float, and the comparison between two floats is unreliable.

Thus, replace the lines with:

```
var precision = divide.toFixed(2);
if (precision == '1.77') {
    orientation = "PORTRAIT";
} 
else if(precision == '0.56') {
    orientation = "LANDSCAPE";
} 
else if(resultHeight === resultWidth){
    orientation = "SQUARE";
}
console.log(orientation);
```

(I've also used `else if` instead of more `if`'s. Also, you may want to handle the case when orientation will be empty)

#### PS

I agree with @Mr.Manhattan's comment to your question. You don't really need to get the exact aspect ratio, normally. Just check the three cases:

- *if* `width > height`, it's landscape
- *else if* `width < height`, it's portrait
- *else* it's square (no need to check `else if(width == height)` as if it's not greater nor lesser it must be equal)

Comment: I've implemented the simpler logic: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/kmbo423j/, but when applied to the project, its still showing all cropping results as "SQUARE".

Comment: @Matt So maybe the selector is not matching the element? What do you get if you place `console.log(resultHeight, resultWidth)`?

Comment: @Matt not on the fiddle, but on your project where it's not working! :)

Comment: It's working now. The img tag didn't have the `#result` id, after some other changes had been made. Thanks!